# How to take only first four elements of every strings from a list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list in pyspark where list looks like

```
result = ['2016-12-11T04:12:58.797', '2016-12-11T03:50:28.253', '2016-12-11T03:49:52.613', '2016-12-11T03:37:49.857']
```

I have to fetch only the year from the list. What I tried is

```
resultYear = result[0:4]
```

But, I know this is not the solution. I am very new to python and pyspark, so I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Use `[r[0:4] for r in result]` or (more shorter) `[r[:4] for r in result]`

Comment: If it's a list like your code example, it's standard python. `[element[:4] for element in result]`. If `result` is still in the form of a RDD, you can do the operation in parallel: `result.map(lambda element: element[:4])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, you simply have to iterate through the list and get the first 4 letters for each element of the list:

```
for element in result:
    year = element[:4] 
    # do what you want with this, e.g print it
    print(year)

>>>2016
>>>2016
...
```

But a more concise way to do it is list comprehension:

```
r = [el[:4] for element in result]
# returns a list of years

print(r)
>>> ['2016', '2016',...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string split function and split the string where 'T' occurs and use the string before character 'T'

**INPUT**

```
result = ['2016-12-11T04:12:58.797', '2016-12-11T03:50:28.253', '2016-12-11T03:49:52.613', '2016-12-11T03:37:49.857']
result = [(r.split('-')[0]) for r in result]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['2016', '2016', '2016', '2016']
```

Comment: Only year is required.